# When I take data from Firebase My Html page shows [object Object]

Tags: javascript, firebase

```js
function snapshotToArray(snapshot) {
    var returnArr = [];

    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var item = childSnapshot.val();
        item.key = childSnapshot.key;

        returnArr.push(item);
    });

    return returnArr;
};
firebase.database().ref('books').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    const list_div = document.querySelector("#list");
    list_div.innerHTML += "<div class='list-item'><h3></h3>" + snapshot.val() + "</div>"
    console.log(snapshotToArray(snapshot));
});
```

```html
 <div class="main-list" id="list">
    <div class="list-item">
        <h3>Kitaplarım:</h3>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**That's my html page result**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38wIw.png)

I've been trying to solve it for 3 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML will not understand js objects, so you have to pass all values as string, in the current situation `snapshot.val()` is an object, to overcome this issue you can simply replace `snapshot.val()` with `JSON.stringify(snapshot.val())`